# PHP: Resolve Internal File Path using Shortened URL

Tags: php, url-rewriting, url-shortener

### My DocRoot:

/var/www/project/templates/index.html
/var/www/project/templates/about.html
/var/www/project/templates/contact.html
/var/www/project/templates/press/2013/01/01/mypresspost1
/var/www/project/templates/press/2013/01/02/mypresspost2
/var/www/project/templates/blog/2013/01/01/myblogpost1
/var/www/project/templates/blog/2013/01/02/myblogpost2

### The Goal:

Find internal file path using shortened URL.
So if I hit `mysite.com/myblogpost2` I will actually be loading `/blog/2013/01/02/myblogpost2`
I am using a templating engine so the path becomes usable in front end like: `{include file="{$path}"}`

### My Bootstrap:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/index.php
RewriteRule .* /index.php
```

Let's assume I already have a method to snag `myblogpost2` string from the URI.
Now this just becomes a matter of resolving the internal path so I can set `$path`

### Ideas:

*I have a couple ideas, these are just to illustrate my problem better. 
Ultimately I am looking for the best route so any advice is welcome.*

**Use JSON from a flat file:**

```
{
    "myblogpost1":   {longpath:"/blog/2013/01/01/myblogpost1"},
    "myblogpost2":   {longpath:"/blog/2013/01/02/myblogpost2"}
}

$string = "myblogpost1";
$path = objJsonResp[$string]->longpath;
```

**Query a table:**

```
$path = SELECT longPath FROM shortUrls WHERE name = :name
```

Comment: I think your idea makes a lot of sense. Just be careful that the names  don't overlap.

Comment: I'd use a database also. For every blog entry create a "permalink" which is short. If the user lands on the permalink, get long url from the DB and use it as needed (you could use 301 to redirect client to the long url so you wouldn't have to worry about paths etc)

Comment: i can only stress Carl Saldanhas statement: no clashes! otherwise only the newest/oldest (depends on sorting) entry will ever be shown with the short url

Answer (score 0):

Since you will have dynamic created entries, i would do this with a mysql table.
within creation of the "alias":

- Create the alias of the title, remove special chars and so on. spaces to underscores ... etc.
- Check if there already exist an alias of that string
- if so place a -1 at the end, check again, if it still exist increment the number till a unique one found.
- Save the alias and and the destination.
- I think you have a unique ID, so store this ID because maybe you change the date and the destination url is not the same as it was.
- Within the .htaccess it should be clear that you need to rewrite all incoming requests to a specific file which check the string if it is an alias.
- If so you got the unique ID from that "page" then you could redirect with the location header by reading out the date of the post and build with this information the actual url.
- would cache this "build up" in order to not loose performance.